# How to fix user input as the variable assignment works fine

Tags: python

My code doesn't give the desired output when I use user input but it works fine when I use a simple variable assignment.

I checked both user input and variable. Both are of type String.

When I use Input, it gives below error: print("\nIPAbuse check for the IP Address: {} \nDatabase Check: \nConfidence of Abuse: \nISP: {} \nUsage: {} \nDomain Name: {} \nCountry: {} \nCity: {}".format(num,description1,description2,isp,usage,domain,country,city)) NameError: name 'description1' is not defined

```
# sys.stdout.write("Enter Source IP Address: ")
# sys.stdout.flush()
# ip = sys.stdin.readline()
ip = '212.165.108.173'
url = ""
num = str(ip)
req = requests.get(url + num)
html = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

try: 
    div = soup.find('div', {"class": "well"})
    description1 = div.h3.text.strip()
    description2 = div.p.text.strip()
    isp = soup.find("th", text="ISP").find_next_sibling("td").text.strip()
    usage = soup.find("th", text="Usage Type").find_next_sibling("td").text.strip()
    domain = soup.find("th", text="Domain Name").find_next_sibling("td").text.strip()
    country = soup.find("th", text="Country").find_next_sibling("td").text.strip()
    city = soup.find("th", text="City").find_next_sibling("td").text.strip()
except:
    isp = 'Invalid'
    usage = 'Invalid'
    domain = 'Invalid'
    country = 'Invalid'
    city = 'Invalid'


print(
    "num, description1, description2, isp, usage, domain, country, city)
```

Comment: What desired output? What's not happening that you want to happen?

Comment: You should use the built-in [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function for getting user input

Comment: Desired Output should be like below and it works fine when I use Variable assignment.                                                                                              IPAbuse check for the IP Address: 212.165.108.173
Database Check:
Confidence of Abuse:
ISP: 212.165.108.173 was found in our database!
Usage: This IP was reported 4 times. Confidence of Abuse is 0%: ?
Domain Name: Inmarsat Solutions B.V.
Country: Fixed Line ISP
City: inmarsat.com

Comment: And what happens when you use the user input?

Comment: But when I use Input, it gives below error:                                                                          print("\nIPAbuse check for the IP Address: {} \nDatabase Check:  \nConfidence of Abuse: \nISP: {} \nUsage: {} \nDomain Name: {} \nCountry: {} \nCity: {}".format(num,description1,description2,isp,usage,domain,country,city))
NameError: name 'description1' is not defined

Comment: `div = soup.find('div', {"class": "well"})` is throwing an exception which then means that `description1` is never defined

Comment: You should see what exception you're getting instead of suppressing it.

Comment: It is a main thing when having problems with code to post in the question the error or wrong output rather than having it in the comments. You should edit that into your question

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Tom... I am new to this forum. I have added error in the question.. Will take care in future..

Answer (score 0):

`readline()` adds a '\n' character to the input, so it's going to be different than if you make it a hardcoded assignment like `ip = '212.165.108.173'`. The newline char is messing up the request. As a quick patch, confirm that the last character of the user input is '\n' and try making sure that character doesn't get in the url for the request. On the other hand, I'd also suggest going for [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) like someone said in the comments (if only because that one does not add the \n at the end).

Comment: Awesome Guys.. Thank you.. I just used input() and its working perfectly fine now.. Cheers..